# Recreate URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Browser Current URL is:

```
http://localhost/a_project/index.html
```

I have a Ajax code calling a PHP file who checks the login details and return a unique id if found in database else returns false. On Ajax success i want to create a URL and redirect the browser to that. I tried following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'site_api/user_login.php',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  data: formData,
  success: function(res) {
    if (res > 0) {
      var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
      window.location = pathArray[1] + "/my%20page.html?id=" + res;
    } else {
      $('#login_error').html('Invalid Credentials. Please try again.');
    }

  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
  }
});
```

But it always result in following URL:

```
http://localhost/a_project/a_project/my%20page.html?id=20
```

Instead it should be routed to:

```
http://localhost/a_project/my%20page.html?id=20
```

I have a feeling that i am missing something but not sure what.

Comment: you're setting location to "a_project/...." - this is relative to the current location http://localhost/a_project/ ... hence the doubling of a_project - try `window.location = "my%20page.html?id="+res;` - no leading /

Comment: I already did, still no luck. It routes to http://localhost/my%20page.html?id=20

Comment: in that case ... try `"/" + pathArray[1] + "/my%20page.html?id="+res;` - that should work

Comment: @JaromandaX What you suggested didn't work exactly but it did helped me in correcting the error. I changed my code to following and it worked fine: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + pathArray[1] + "/my%20page.html?id="+res

Comment: it's odd that yo need the host in some cases but not in others ... I was going to suggest `window.location = "./my%20page.html?id="+res;` as well

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
window.location = window.location.origin + '/a_project/my%20page.html?id=20' + res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to generate the URL?

As you site root is `http://localhost/a_project/`, the pages `index.html` and `my page.html` are in the same directory. You can use relative path.

Just use `"my page.html?id=" + res`

And I would strongly recommend **NOT** to have spaces in URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'site_api/user_login.php',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(res) {
        if (res > 0) {
            location.href = "my%20page.html?id=" + res;
        } else {
            $('#login_error').html('Invalid Credentials. Please try again.');
        }

    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add A **Base URL** in the javascript then concatinate with the original Url

```
 var baseUrl="http://example.com/";
$.ajax({
            url: 'site_api/user_login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function(res)
            {
                if(res > 0){
                    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
                    window.location =baseUrl+ pathArray[1] + "/my%20page.html?id="+res; //changes Here
                } else {
                    $('#login_error').html('Invalid Credentials. Please try again.');
                }

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                alert (xhr.status);
            }
        });
```